# How to check page title in selenide

Tags: java, selenide

How to check page title in Selenide using `shouldHave` assertion?

In 'Selenium' it will be the next code:

```
Assert.assertEquals(title(), "Your page title");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't find any code samples in documentation, but the next code solved my problem:

```
$("title").shouldHave(attribute("text", "Your page title"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Selenide.title()` method to get page title text

Answer (score 2):

```
$("title").shouldHave(text("title text"));
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Selenide 5.25.0 (September 2021), you can use this:

```java
webdriver().shouldHave(title("Your page title"));
```

Here are the corresponding imports:

```java
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.webdriver;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverConditions.title;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will extract the title from the page.

```
String tile= $(By.xpath("To your title tag")).innerText().toString();
```

Comment: this is not answer, because question was about selenide.